# Alignment for report columns

Tags: alignment, data-visualisation

I am currently creating a Crystal report, but having difficulty on how to align certain columns.  I have a `Social Security`, `employee_name`, `Check Number` and `Amount`.

I understand that the amounts should be right aligned so the decimals line up, but how should the `Social Security` column be aligned?  I understand it is a 'Number' but it doesn't seem like a normal number that should be right aligned.  I also am concerned about my `Check Number` column.  This does have check numbers that are 10 characters long, but there is a chance my column can have "DIRDEP" for direct deposit.  Should this be left align, or right aligned?

Any thoughts are appreciated.

```
    SOCIAL SEC      EMPLOYEE          CHECK      AMOUNT
    000000000     JOHN SMITH     0000001122      123.12
    000000000     JOE SMITH      0000001123      321.21
    000000000     JIM SMITH          DIRDEP      123.21
```

or

```
    SOCIAL SEC     EMPLOYEE       CHECK           AMOUNT
     000000000     JOHN SMITH     0000001122      123.12
     000000000     JOE SMITH      0000001123      321.21
     000000000     JIM SMITH      DIRDEP          123.21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would align...

- SSN on center - always 9 numbers (11 with hyphens) so widths vary only slightly based upon characters. Center alignment would provide the least visual disturbance in my opinion
- Name to left - Only real "text field" so left align leads to easiest ingestion of data.
- check to right - Critical aspect is often the last 4 or 5 digits so right align seems best.
- amount on decimal.

I could be incorrect, but as far as I know there are no rules about anything more than dollar figures. It all comes down to what looks pleasing to you and makes scanning the data easiest.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the answer.  I have been creating reports that are pleasing to the eye, but wanted to see if there were standards.  Thanks.